# LAN problem with Age of Empires and Company of Heroes

Tags: networking, age-of-empires-iii, company-of-heroes

Recently, I have had trouble connecting two laptops on the same Wi-Fi hotspot to play a local game of the original Age of Empires 3. I have been able for some time to use it with no problem in the past, after fixing some other issues. When one laptop hosts a game, the other one cannot see the game, or when the order of the laptops is switched, the laptop trying to join can see that the game exists, but I get no response at all when I click the join button. I believe that the only change since it used to work was that we changed our Wi-Fi hotspot. At the same time as the problem started, I have also had similar problems with the original Age of Empires 2 and the original Company of Heroes game.

I have updated the games, they are running on the same compatibility mode, and Windows Firewall is off when I try to play. I have also tried using my phone's personal hotspot, which did not work.